# Django shell is used to add data in the database. But the same can be done using admin page. So what is the need for using shell

Tags: django-models

Admin page can be used to add data in the app if I had registered it on **admin.py**.

So why should I use django **shell** to add data in my database?

Answer (score 0):

Django shell is used quickly testing out code.

If you just want to add data, you can happily use admin and forget about Django shell.

If you are trying out code that adds data, shell can be useful.

Comment: Shell is used to create objects for the classes in models. Am I right or not?

Comment: Strictl speaking, you're not 100% right. Shell is used for whatever you want to that can be done by code. You can do a lot more via shell than just adding objects.